not able to open web page using django
I'm using the code below code for opening a webpage (my_app1) using django in Google Cloudshell, after  running server showing below error in serverlink).

Using the URLconf defined in demoproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^my_app1/$

The empty path didn’t match any of these.

urls
from django.urls import include, re_path
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import my_app, my_ap
urlpatterns = \[
re_path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
re_path(r'^my_app1/$', my_ap),
\]

views
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_app(request):
return HttpResponse("this is response")

def my_ap(request):
return HttpResponse("hi buddy")

How do I get the response hi buddy after running server?

what url are you going to url/my_app1/ ?

try ip:port/my_app1/4.

Or change re_path(r'^my_app1/$', my_ap), to re_path('', my_ap),  .

Just in case. Did you add the app in the Settings.py?

his urls don't match. that's the problem. As @iklinac also pointed out. Please try my answer and respond with the status.

Here is a good link https://dev.to/markpy/understanding-django-httpresponse-49dj But as Pycm mentioned, the urls do not match.

I am sorry. but that link is not informative. it's a url matching problem.

Did you solve your problem? Did you try my answer? Comment on my answer with your feedback. So I can help you..

To match empty path, there should be something like path('', my_ap),.
As the error The empty path didn’t match any of these. says, you are trying to access path ip:port without any sub path(ip:port/path1).
But your url re_path(r'^my_app1/$', my_ap), only accept path my_app1.
try ip:port/my_app1/4.
Or change re_path(r'^my_app1/$', my_ap), to path('', my_ap),.
